# How to pass Variables return value in adf pipelines

Tags: azure-data-factory, oracle-adf

In child pipeline1 I passed if condition in that true statement variable 1 is executed and in false statement variable2 is executed.

Now in ChildPipeline2 parameter I am passing value is
@or(activity('childpipeline1'). output.pipelinereturnvalue.variable1,activity('childpipeline1'). output.pipelinereturnvalue.variable2,)

Now 2 cases when true statement executes and variable1 executes the expression is working.

When false statement executes and variable2 executes the expression is not working

Now 2 cases when true statement executes and variable1 executes the expression is working.

When false statement executes and variable2 executes the expression is not working.

I am getting an error like cannot evaluate because variable1 doesn't exist

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the pipeline and\or the pipeline JSON to make your question more understandable.

Comment: @VinceBowdren, I want to see the screenshot of the pipeline in Azure data factory, and that pipeline JSON to better understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The above error occurs when the if expression inside the child pipeline results False. If its false, the variable2 value will be returned as `true` from child pipeline and pipeline don't know about the variable1 because it's not executed in this case.

whereas if it's true, variable1 value will be returned as `true` and still pipeline don't know about variable2. But the reason for pipeline success in this case is `@or()` nature. If the first expression in the `or()` is `true`, then it won't check the second expression and it will give the total result as `true`.

To achieve your requirement, follow the below steps.

In **child pipeline1 True activities of if**, add both variable1 and variable2. If its `true`, give the values as `true` for variable1 and `false` for variable2.

[image]

Do the same in False activities of if, but give `true` for variable2 and `false` for the variable2.

[image]

Now, whatever might be the if expression result(True or False), both variables with proper values with be returned from the child pipeline1 and `@or(activity('Execute Pipeline1').output.pipelineReturnValue.var1,activity('Execute Pipeline1').output.pipelineReturnValue.var2)` will give correct value which you can pass to your next pipeline as per your requirement.

[image]